# Creating a list using range function

Tags: range

I am looking to create a list using range function without having to type in 0-100. It is not clear to me how to use the range function in python as I am a beginner. Is there a way to do this? Thank you

Comment: You just wrap the `range` function with a `list` function like `x = list(range(101))`

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, `range` returns an iterable, you can specify a `start` and an `end+1` like this:

```py
an_iterable = range(0,101)
```

Then you can turn it into a list like this:

```py
a_list = list(an_iterable)
```